# Project Euler #19: Counting Sundays in the 20th century using Pandas

Tags: python, programming-challenge, datetime, python-2.x, pandas

[Project Euler #19](https://projecteuler.net/problem=19) asks:

> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

I'm hoping I wasn't too off course from the spirit of the exercise by making use of my favorite libraries: `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1901', end='12/31/2000', freq='D')
count = 0
for date in rng:
    if date.day == 1 and date.weekday() == 6:
        count += 1
count
```

It's a rather simple problem and a rather simple solution. I just made use of the `date_range` function that pandas has builtin that works well with `datetime` objects in python.

While I don't think my usual questions apply. Some specific questions:

- Is it pythonic to run the for loop as such, or would a list comprehension surrounded by a len be more pythonic, e.g. `len([x for x in rng if date.day == 1 and date.weekday() == 6])`? Or is something entirely else even more pythonic?
- Is there a way to avoid iterating over an object as large as `rng` is with it's 30,000+ items to avoid memory usage? If so what would be a preferred method (just pseudo-code or however you prefer to explain.)
- As my attention has been brought to how powerful `itertools` is when improving performance and substituting lists for generators, I'm wondering how I would improve upon the below code with `itertools` if there is any such a way.

Comment: `I'm hoping I wasn't too off course from the spirit of the exercise by making use of my favorite libraries` The spirit of Project Euler is to learn. You know have learned how to do it. Next step is to learn whether this is the most Pythonic way to do it. You did not go against any spirit.

Comment: Just a small note: you could set a `freq` such that rng only contains sundays or first of months. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445174/date-ranges-in-pandas )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good to use a library rather than re-inventing everything yourself. Just be sure to avoid explicit looping in Python:

```
sum(date.day == 1 and date.weekday() == 6 for date in rng)
```

The above sums the number of times that `date.day == 1 and date.weekday() == 6` automatically, with no loops of counters, It should also be more efficient (`sum` is implemented in C)

Comment: This is really clever thanks! I hadn't thought to use the `and` clause like that in a loop. Also good to know regarding `sum()`

Comment: @mburke05 Note that this works because `True` can be coerced to 1, and `False` can be coerced to 0.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan thanks! I did indeed work that out through some trial and error in IDLE after having read his solution. Are there any other cases like that worth knowing? I've seen people throw around things like `while None` or `while a` where a is an empty list and things like that that I wouldn't normally associate with a boolean identity.

Comment: @mburke05 That's called "truthiness" in Python. Regardless of type, variables can be evaluated as booleans. There's a write up of it [here](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs258/truthiness-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `rng` to mean `range`. I know you were avoiding the builtin function, but it's not clear. It also could be mistaken to mean Random Number Generator (though the usage makes it clear that's not the case). Even if you could use `range`, I would advise against it. `range` doesn't really describe what the list contains, just the type of list it is. Instead, name things more for their purpose and contents than meta information about the contents. Looking at the `for` loop, there's an obvious name to use, `dates`.

Also ending with just `count` by itself, not even being printed, is odd. It may come out right in the IDE you use but it often will just pass by unnoticed. Call `print` and ideally add text around it

```
print("There are {} first day of the month Sundays in the 20th century.".format(count))
```

`str.format` is the accepted way to format variables into strings. It will call the `str()` method on anything passed to it to coerce them to strings. It's preferable to using `"string" + str(var) + "string"` because it's clearer and can be shorter even if it might not seem like it from this example, but imagine this:

```
"My string has two variables, " + str(var) " and the other one is " + str(var)
```

Versus

```
"My string has two variables, {} and the other one is {}".format(var, var)
```

But also `str.format` has a lot of useful syntax to help format strings better. I wont go into them here as you don't need them for this script, but take a look over [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

You asked about `join`, but that has a fundamentally different purpose. `join` takes a collection parameter, like a list, and will make a string by concatenating the list together. It doesn't perform any string conversion and doesn't allow you to insert arbitrary text between values. I definitely wouldn't use it in this case.

Comment: Thanks will do, I used `rng` simply because I recall it being in an example in the pandas documentation. Also, the `count` statement was simply due to my IDE as you noted (I work mostly in Jupyter, is this something I shouldn't be doing? I've seen debate on this and that between IDLE vs. PyCharm vs. iPython, etc.) Random question, could you explain the choice to use .format and not .join or even just `"Your str"` + `str(var)` where `var` is our number (count in this case.) Thanks!

Comment: Whatever IDE you want to use is fine, but when I run this (just in IDLE) it gives a very different result, no output at all. Just placing a variable by itself isn't a trustworthy or reliable means to do anything. I'll edit my answer to explain a bit about `format`.